# How to validate CNIC no in mvc by regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want validate the CNIC no(computed national identity card no). 
I want to take input from client like (12345-1234567-1) no character except dashes. I wrote below regular expression

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{5}-[-|]-[0-9]{7}-[-|]-[0-9]{1}")]
public string NICNo { get; set; }
```

But when I submit the from it shows the whole regular expression in validation error Like below

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need `[-|]`, use

```
^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FiCznC/1). Note the `$` at the end requiring the end of string.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{5}` - 5 digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{7}` - 7 digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]` - a single digit (no need "saying" `{1}`)
- `$` - end of string anchor.

In code:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]$", ErrorMessage = "CNIC No must follow the XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X format!")]
public string NICNo { get; set; }
```

Comment: thanks @Wiktor Stribizew .... now it works but still showing the whole regular expression shows in validation error as i mention in the above screen shot

Comment: Is it some refresh issue? If the regex validation passes, there should be no error message, right?

Comment: Stribizew bro what should I use for whitespace regex

Comment: I mean space between two strings